# Separating WAL Log and the data in two two different disk for Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I'm looking for a reference and ways to separating the WAL transaction Logs and the data into two different disk for postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done when you create the cluster:

```
initdb --waldir=/somewhere/else datadir
```

But you can also do it later:

- stop the server
- move `pg_wal` somewhere else
- create a symbolic link `pg_wal` instead that points to the new location

Note that a `pg_basebackup` will not preserve the symbolic link, so if you want to create a standby where `pg_wal` is a symbolic link, you'll need to use the `--waldir` option of `pg_basebackup`.

Comment: Will try it. Actually doing DRBD replcation as well for /dev/sdb as postgres data and /dev/sdc for the wal log and  /dev/sda will be for the system.

Comment: I tried the below but doesn't worked                                                                          
#pg_ctl initdb -X /var/lib/pg_wal -D /var/lib/pgsql/data 
(pg_ctl: invalid option -- 'X' 
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.)

Comment: The `pg_ctl` documentation will tell you that you have to use `-o` to separate `pg_ctl` options from `initdb` options.

Comment: Please note `initdb` will only affect master/leader node. In order to make it effective on replica nodes too, we need to use `--waldir=waldir` in [pg_backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgbasebackup.html)

Comment: @anasanjaria That is a useful comment. I took the liberty to add it to the answer.